# how to filter "link to existing content" suggestion in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, hook

How can i filter the link given in "link to existing content".

[image]

As in the above image. I just want WSP BANNER TO BE SHOWN.

where WSP BANNER & CALENDAR are custom post_type

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: It helps you this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-permalink-based-off-taxonomy-or-categories?replies=2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there are no ready filters available for this purpose. A [ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21033) has been posted for the request.Lets hope we get one soon.

Till then you can create your own filter.

Open includes/class-wp-editor.php and make folowing changes at line no 712

```
$pt_names = apply_filters('custom_insert_link_suggestion_filter',array_keys( $pts ));
```

we just added a new filter instead of getting all the public post types

Then in your theme add following code to filter the internal link custom post type

```
function my_filter_function($allowed_post_types)
{


if( condition chek)
{
         return array('page','your custom post types');
}
```

}
add_filter('custom_insert_link_suggestion_filter','my_filter_function',10,1);

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that could be helpful for you: [B09 Link to Existing Content](http://wordpress.org/plugins/b09-link-to-existing-content/)

It has a filter called "link_to_existing_content_post_types", that enables you to control which post types should be searched.

You can also use it together with this plugin, if you also want to have complete control over the search results: [Search Everything](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/).

Answer (score 0):

Consider an example where my site is configured on wp.abc.com and I point my root domain www.abc.com to the new site. I need to update the URL's in General Setting. So when I update the URL, it is reflected in menu items etc. Will it be reflected in the content area links aslo?